Generator Matrix of a Code over a Non-unital Ring
I was reading the paper about codes over a non-unital ring $I = \langle a , b \mid 2 a = 0 , 2 b = 0 , a^2 = b , ab =0 \rangle$ which can be seen here. On page 11, Section 6, generator matrices for codes over $I$ are given for specific lengths.
For instance, in $n = 3$, a generator matrix is given by $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & a & b \\ 0 & b & 0. \end{array}  \right)$. The weight distribution according to the paper is given by $[ \langle 0 , 1 \rangle, \langle 1 , 2 \rangle , \langle 2 , 1 \rangle , \langle 3 , 4 \rangle ]$, i.e., the code generated by the above generator matrix has $8$ codewords. My question is why is this the case. Isn't $C = \left\lbrace u (a,a,b) + v (0,b,0) \ | \  u , v \in I \right\rbrace = \{ 000, bb0 \}$?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Your code needs to be a submodule generated by the rows of the generator matrix (the minimal submodule containing these two row vectors), so I believe you need to have both of these codewords, then you need the closure under addition and scalar multiplication.
I get (following the authors and using $c = a+b$):
$$ C = \{ 000, aab, 0b0, acb, 
               bb0,
               ccb, b00, cab \}. $$
This comes from $000$ (in every submodule), $u= aab$ and $v = 0b0$ as the rows of the matrix, $acb = u+v$; then multiplying everything in here by $a$ we get one new vector, $au = bb0$; then we finally get $ccb = u + au$, $b00 = v + au$, and $acb = (u+v) + au$.

Thank you so much for your response, @XXXXXXXXX. Your explanation made me understood the problem.
